# BUG in sprite GameMaker

Tags: sprites, game-maker

In the game you have an object called obj_Corpo, and your image is a 3x3 square. I use it by stretching it horizontally or vertically for 10 or 20 times. Here's an example:

[image]

Acontece que no jogo ele não aparece da forma adequada.

It turns out that in the game it does not appear properly.

[image]

Note that it only gives horizontal error. This began to happen a few days ago, with no explanation. I've tried other colors and the same thing happens (darkened edges).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of stress I found the solution only by increasing the size of the texture pages from 4096 to 8192.

[image]

Comment: It's simple solution but wrong (your game won't work on many computers). Just don't use images bigger than `Texture Pages` → `Size` (split it into smaller parts)

Comment: I do not use large images, but many images. I tried to reduce the size of some, but the quality got really bad.